# Complete a workflow from within an activity

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

Is it possible to complete the workflow from within a custom activity?  I'm trying to create a work flow with several if statements and i'd like the work flow to complete after the first one if the condition is met or else pass on to the next statement etc. As i will have several checks i was planning on creating a custom activity to handle it all for me rather then adding several decision on the work flow as i feel this will make the workflow look complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create an activity derived from NativeActivity you can control the scheduling of child activities.  In essenence you would be creating your own control flow activity.  You would need to create a designer for it as well but that isn't too difficult.